# entities.UserBean cannot be cast to entities.UserBean

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Hey i'm setting up a spring application using hibernate. I'm having some problems with  my enities:

```
 entities.UserBean cannot be cast to entities.UserBean
java.lang.ClassCastException: entities.UserBean cannot be cast to entities.UserBean
    at dao.UserDao.findByUsername(UserDao.java:38)
    at services.UserService.SelByUsername(UserService.java:20)
    at mainapp.servlet.ProvaServlet.doGet(ProvaServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

same with the other one,I've tried adding @Entity(name="Users"), still didn't help, i really don't know what i'm doing wrong. Here you have my entities and configs as well as the dao:

```
package entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class UserBean {
    @Id
    @Column(name="username", length = 16, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    public UserBean(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public UserBean() {

    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Dao:

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import entities.UserBean;
import util.HibernateUtil;

public class UserDao {
    public void InsUser(UserBean user) {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {

            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            session.persist(user);

            tx.commit();
        }
    }

    public void DelUser(UserBean user) {

        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {

            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            session.delete(user);

            tx.commit();
        }
    }

    public UserBean findByUsername(String username) {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            return session.get(UserBean.class, username);
        }
    }

    public List<UserBean> findAll() {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {

            return session.createQuery("FROM Users", UserBean.class).getResultList();
        }
    }
}
```

hibernate config:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/ledger?serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">developer</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- Dialetto SQL del DB a cui ci colleghiamo -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect</property>
        <!-- Proprieta' che indica se stampare a console l'SQL generato -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Scelta della modalita' di aggiornamento dello schema -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- dbcp connection pool configuration -->
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxTotal">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWaitMillis">-1</property>

        <!-- mapping entita' -->
        <mapping class="entities.UserBean" />
        <mapping class="entities.TransactionBean" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.jac</groupId>
    <artifactId>Personale-Ledger</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Personale-Ledger</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Ty in advance.

Edit
[image: project structure]

Comment: The UserBean class is in a separate jar?

Comment: yes each of the code segments are differente .java files

Comment: I mean .JAR file, but antway add serial version UID

Comment: did that, the project is not yet exported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

in my case was this dependecy

Answer (score 0):

Implement Serializable interface for your entities.

```
public Class UserBean implements Serializable{}
```

Comment: Still doen't fix it

Comment: Are you sure both the class files are exactly the same? One thing you can't do is to move this type of class files to a separate jar and add them as dependency

Comment: The project Is not exported, there is just the one class for each entity